# Wordpress customizer overwriting doesnt work

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Unfortunately I have a sudden problem with wordpress that I can not find a solution... I have revised the Tutorstarter theme. Since Elementor did not work I overwrote the header in the Customizer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVQOU.jpg). After I have given the header a sticky function this was no longer functional and looks like in the second screenshot. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N69KD.jpg)

Strangely enough, everything looks as it should in the Customizer. Only not on the live page?

- Server Cache cleared
- Browser Cache cleared
- Removed the code and paste it again
- Writed the Hostinger Support (they said i have to try here)
- tryed to find a solution here